# Swift, Wait for two completion blocks to complete before return list

Tags: swift, completionhandler

Im trying to call out to two separate api endpoints that return some json, the two calls add objects to a list...How can i wait for the two funcs to complete before returning the list to a view controller

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class SearchService {

var searchItemList = [SearchItem]()

func performFetch(keyword: String, count: Int, completion:(items: [SearchItem]?) -> ()){
    >>>// NEED TO WAIT FOR THE fetchItemsA AND fetchItemsB TO FINISH THEM RETURN ‘searchItemList’
}

func fetchItemsA(keyword: String, count: Int, completion:(error:NSError?) -> ())  {
    guard let url = self.searchUrl else {
        return
    }

    let manager = Manager.sharedInstance
        manager.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["keywords": keyword, "count": count], encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON {response in

        …

        for item in items {
            self.searchItemList.append(SearchItem(json: item)!)
        }

        …
        completion(error: resultError)
}

func fetchItemsB(keyword: String, count: Int, completion:(error:NSError?) -> ())  {
    guard let url = self.searchUrl else {
        return
    }

        let manager = Manager.sharedInstance
            manager.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["keywords": keyword, "count": count], encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON {response in

    …

    for item in items {
        self.searchItemList.append(SearchItem(json: item)!)
    }

    …
            completion(error: resultError)
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Can't you combine the search predicates to use only **one** API call?

Comment: Cheers @vadin , you got me thinking...  http://stackoverflow.com/q/28791349/4154338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API are different you could try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409737/2000162). If you want to do two asynchronous requests the simplest solution would be count the requests and check in the completion how many requests has finished (first solution in the answer). Remember that the response can be success or error.